Issue with NetBarcode 1.7.2 nuget package and SixLabors.Fonts.Measure() function
I am implementing NetBarcode version 1.7.2 in order to create a barcode based on a string as input.
This version of NetBarcode has a GetImage() function that in turn uses SixLabors.Fonts.TextMeasurer that should have a Measure(string text, TextOptions options) function.
However, when I run my function the following exception occurs:

System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'SixLabors.Fonts.FontRectangle SixLabors.Fonts.TextMeasurer.Measure(System.String, SixLabors.Fonts.TextOptions)'.
at NetBarcode.Barcode.GenerateImage()
at NetBarcode.Barcode.GetImage()

Looking into this I found the following inside the Barcode.GenerateImage (called by GetImage()) function:
FontRectangle fontRectangle = TextMeasurer.Measure(_data, labelTextOptions);

The Measure() function is blue here, indicating that it doesn't exist. When diving into the TextMeasurer class I can not not find a Measure() function. Only MeasureAdvance, MeasureSize, MeasureBounds and some others.
I see that this changed in SixLabors version 1.0.0 before this the function was called Measure(). I can not use an older version of SixLabors because ClosedXML requires a version higher than 1.0.0.
What can I do now? Search for a new Nuget Package? Implement an old version of the NetBarcode Nuget? I see that it went to SixLabors as of version 1.5 because .Net6 only works on Windows from that point on, I don't know if I can use that since we work with AWS Lambda's
I tried changing the Measure() function to MeasureAdvance()

Did you read the NetBarcode ReadMe on NuGet which states: There is a small compatibility break only if you are manipulating the image with the GetImage method or customizing font and color. In these cases the namespaces have changed to SixLabors.ImageSharp. If one clicks on Project Website one can view the source code for each on Github.

I thought I did read that, but it probably didn't land somewhere in my head.
I still don't really understand what they mean by "the namespaces have changed to SixLabors.ImageSharp" however.
Does this mean I have to change something in the code? I've really tried to wrap my head around it but I've only been programming for about a year so this is still all very confusing to me

I'm not familiar with NetBarcode - I just looked up the information for it. I wouldn't  focus too much on the choice of words. Look at the source code in the Github repository which is where one is taken if one clicks on Project Website.

If you're using Visual Studio one can use Object Browser to see information. However, Object Browser doesn't show as an option for a .NET project. As a workaround, add a Class Library (.NET Framework) project to your solution. Then, in Solution Explorer (View => Solution Explorer) expand the class library (ie: ClassLibrary1. Expand References.  Right-click System and select View in Object Browser. Once Object Browser opens you can expand NetBarcode, SixLabors.Fonts, SixLabors.ImageSharp and SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing to see desired information.

It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. From the content of your post, it seems that you may be too focused on following a particular approach rather than focusing on the desired outcome. You may consider re-writing your post to first mention what you're trying to accomplish (ie: the desired outcome). Then mention what you've researched/found/tried - if appropriate, include URLs.
